# Javascript or Jquery merge 2 pdf files into one in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, pdf

I am trying to merge two pdf files into one single document in my html page when clicking some button, is it posible ?, have any one of you ever tried to do so and had success ?

thanks in advance to any good idea

Comment: how are u trying to do that?

Comment: by the moment I was trying the different methods described in several answers in here and Github regarding the same issue but no body seems to have a solution yet with the most popular libraries, jsPDF for example, still not work to merge, and so on

Answer (score -2):

You can take a look at this plugin
[Merge PDF into one file](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js)

it can solve your problem.

Comment: thanks, I´ll hit it again... I´ve been trying this one a couple of days but nothing clear by the moment, but this time I´m gonna read between the lines to see what I´ve missed